# How to use Preview version of office-js Excel API?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I want to use Preview features of office-js Excel API (specifically DataValidation).

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-data-validation) says that I should use Beta version of the library and they provide a link but I have no idea what to do with it.

What I did so far:
I have added the js path to `index.html`.
I copied types from ts file to file in `node_modules`.

But it doesn't seem like a good solution since whenever I update `@types/office-js` I would also have to copy source again...

Comment: The intention is that you reference the beta URLs in `<script>` tags in the HTML file. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Yes, but only doing this doesn't let me use TypeScript classes, so in order to do so, I had to copy ts file into my sources...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to use preview Api you only need:

1. Install l[atest insiders fast build](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Office-Insider-f4208185-b63a-4b68-9c7a-9a32d2411c16), AND
2. refer to the BETA
   CDN for office.js and if you will use typescript the typescript
   library: here are the URLs you need to use, as Ricky suggests make sure you add those references to your HTML or JS files in your web app.

https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.d.ts

Comment: Thanks! But why do I need Office Insider? Isn't it for end product review instead of developer preview?

Comment: So then is it possible to deploy an addin using preview version? (I know it is recommended but I need dataValidation feature that is only available in preview so far)

Comment: i dont recommend you to do that, in fact the store will reject your add-in for the store if you are using the preview CDN. in your own environment you could do it, with the risk of knowing we reserve the right to change any method on preview at any time.

Comment: I see, and is it possible for you to tell me when the data validation will be released in the stable channel? I am asking because it is a crucial feature of our app.

Comment: the data validation specifically is quite solid right now. ITs a strong candidate to be released in our next batch. i think that will happen no later than this year.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using angular follow these steps.

Refer to the beta office js cdn.

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you need type definition for beta version, install this.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/office-js-preview
```

If you were already using the production version, uninstall it:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/office-js
```

Mention the following type in tsconfig.app.json like this (if types is already empty).

```
"types": ["office-js-preview"]
```