# Switching Office Javascript APIs to Preview on Yeoman Office Generated project

Tags: excel, visual-studio-code, office-js, office-addins, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to access the Office Javascript Preview APIs on my Angular Yeoman Generated project. I am writing this Office add-in on a Mac in Visual Studio Code. I wrote code on Script Lab with the preview library but do not know how to do the same for the Yeoman generated Office project. When I try to access the ".addFromBase64()" function, I get:

> "Property 'addFromBase64' does not exist on type 'WorksheetCollection'.ts(2339)"

I have already tried changing the CDN references from [Javascript 1.8 APIs](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.8/hosted/office.js)
to the [Javascript Beta (Preview) APIs](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js) and added the [@types suggested by the note next to the section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#insert-a-copy-of-an-existing-workbook-into-the-current-one-preview). I found and replaced 2 instances of the 1.8 APIs in 'commands.html' and 'taskpane.html'.

I have tried the steps for [Updating an Office Add-in project created with a text editor or other IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/update-your-javascript-api-for-office-and-manifest-schema-version#updating-an-office-add-in-project-created-with-a-text-editor-or-other-ide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else besides Daniel and me ever wants to know this:

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441910/how-to-use-preview-version-of-office-js-excel-api), in addition to changing the CDN referernces and adding the preview @types, you need to uninstall the production @types with

```
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/office-js
```

Answer (score 0):

We confirmed the addFromBase64 should works in MAC from https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-win32-16.00.debug.js

Please clear cache and try again to see if works.